# Force WiFi calling of SIM2 over data of SIM1

Tags: dual-sim, cellular-radio, wifi-calling

Is there any way I can disable the radio of SIM2 so I can only have 1 active SIM and 1 WiFi calling? Can I use ADB to achieve this, or anything else that doesn't need root or bootloader unlocked?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.